# insert data from more than one excel sheet of one file into table using SSIS?

Tags: sql, ssis

i have one excel file that contains `a`1 to `a5` rows with values now `a6= sum(a1:a5)`

I want `a6` value to be inserted into database using ssis package

How can i do mapping ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to ignore the first 5 rows and take the value in the 6th, use the SQL Server Destination component and set the first row and last row to insert as explained by Jiqin Ma [Import single cell](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1930/use-ssis-to-import-one-cell-of-an-excel-file-into-sql-server/)